# Scraping Rottentomates score with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im working on scraping some data from rottentomatoes for my university project
but i cannot scrape tomatometer score

https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/doctor_strange_in_the_multiverse_of_madness

[image]

my codeline is

```py
tomato = bs.find('span', {'class':'percentage'}, {'data-qa':'tomatometer'}).text
```

I've tried several ways but none of them working

Answer (score 2):

The data you see is stored in `<score-board>` tag within the page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/doctor_strange_in_the_multiverse_of_madness"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

board = soup.find("score-board")
print(
    f'Audience Score: {board["audiencescore"]}% Tomatometer: {board["tomatometerscore"]}%'
)
```

Prints:

```
Audience Score: 87% Tomatometer: 75%
```